# How to map values by column names at pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What do i want - is to map column names into keys.
For example:

```
#+-------+----------+
#|key1   |key2      |
#+-------+----------+
#|value1 |value2    |
#|value3 |value4    |
#+-------+----------+
```

Will be transformed to

```
#+-------+----------+
#|   keys|values    |
#+-------+----------+
#|key1   |value1    |
#|key1   |value2    |
#|key2   |value3    |
#|key2   |value4    |
#+-------+----------+
```

In HiveQL i can wrote something similar to

```
select distinct key, velue
    from xxx
    lateral view explode(map(
            'key1', key1,
            'key2', key2) tab as key, value
```

But how to wrote it at pyspark.
I can use createtemptable but i think it's not best solution/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`create_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=pivot#pyspark.sql.functions.create_map) function to create a Map column and then explode it.

`create_map` needs a list of column expressions that are grouped
as key-value pairs. Such a list can be created using for comprehension on DataFrame columns:

```
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, create_map, explode


data = [("value1", "value2"), ("value3", "value4")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["key1", "key2"])

key_values = create_map(*(chain(*[(lit(name), col(name)) for name in df.columns])))

df.select(explode(key_values)).show()

+----+------+
| key| value|
+----+------+
|key1|value1|
|key2|value2|
|key1|value3|
|key2|value4|
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```sql
select 'key1' as keys,
       key1 as values
from xxx
union all 
select 'key2' as keys,
       key2 as values
from xxx
```

put that is `spark.sql()`.